# Protect OData API calls from data spoofing from inside by internal user

Tags: security, odata, sapui5

A question regarding securitizing OData API calls in the SAPUI5 application.

In the legacy system, once a user successfully passed an authorization, it is possible to send a request with a User ID and desired data directly from a client-side to OData API without any additional security check on a server side.

My concern is that any authorized user in the system can behave as a trojan, theoretically spoofing their own User ID and performing some actions under the name of another user. As mitigation mean, there is an option to encapsulate an OData API from a client-side by introducing a server-side wrapper, which will perform a sender authentication before forwarding request to the OData API.

Are there already some out-of-box approaches in SAPUI5 platform to secure the use of OData API, to ensure that the request sender can't fake a User ID and do something in a system under another name?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question correctly. Use HTTPS to secure the transported data.

Comment: @iPirat, the question is not about the man-in-the-middle threat, but how to ensure that the authorized person can't send a request to `OData API` providing identification data (`User ID`) of someone else. Is there any built-in approach to verify an authentic of a request sender? I tried to paraphrase the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, the access to OData service is not anonymous, you will have some sort of “currently logged in user” information on the server.

Now, it is an important task of the service implementation to check if the user is allowed to access the data he is requesting.

I’ll make up some sample requests.

```
/UserData('ALICE')
/UserData('BOB')
```

The service implementation **must** check if the requesting user is allowed to get the data. For example, Alice will get the data for the first request, and a 404 for the second request. Bob the other way around. A superuser may get the data for both.

As another example, something like that may be possible: every employee can access own data, a team lead is allowed to access data of everyone in her team.

Bottom line: service must check if the user is allowed to access the data.

Comment: thanks for the response, the question is if this check must be implemented manually by a developer or there is some built-in into `OData API` functionality to check user identity?

Comment: yes, this must be done by developer. The only thing that can be done semi-automatically is checking if the user is allowed to access the service at all (by assigning the user some object that authorizes the user to use the service). What type of parameter is passed to the service and patameters meaning, only the service itself (the developer of the service) is able to check. it is up to developer (in the sence of architecture) to implement the check inside the code or make it configurable, though.